# MIME-Types in JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm developing an application using Apaches Jsoup to download a homepage. Now is my question: is it possible to define the MIME-types in SOUP. My aim is, just to load the text of the selected homepage and to exclude images from loading.

My Code:

```
Document doc = null;
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Comment: When you connect to a web page with JSoup, you only get the reply to that single HTTP request. That means - it's just the HTML, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a URL with Jsoup, it will only fetch that URL, not any external resources referenced by the document at that URL. So, you have already achieved your stated aim.